# Error at running docker on raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

install docker on Rasberry Pi 3B+ stretch follow this guide

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script

and install docker-compose via pip install.

but error on

`docker run --rm -it tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.5 /bin/sh`

standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"

but its work with this.

`docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/sh`

is it cause incompatible between image and rpi?

Comment: It's strange because `docker run --rm -it tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.5 /bin/sh` works in a PC and I don't have an available Rpi3 to check it just now, but let me recommend you to do: docker run --rm -d tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.5 sleep infinity` and after that enter with `docker exec`, inspect with `docker inspect` and `docker logs` and try to execute internally manually. Let's see

Comment: $ docker run --rm -d tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.5 /bin/sh sleep infinity
>> 8939fd542678fd294c7b0592524a1e5c19fe5a3376adbd683329bba96256dab6

Comment: $ docker ps
// show nothing

$ docker ps -a
// show thresh  from failed docker-compose
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
2aab9d8a0702        3960fe403dd3        "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   11 minutes ago      Exited (1) 11 minutes ago                       admiring_swirles

Comment: Note that I wrote `docker run -d` not `-ti` with sleep infinity

Comment: this command wrong?

docker run --rm -d tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.5 sleep infinity
e9490eebd5fb1d161359d05192042be477d87aaa2e813e4fff69a329cd22675d

Comment: Yes, and after that, `docker exec -ti e9490eebd5fb1d161359d05192042be477d87aaa2e813e4fff69a329cd22675d bash`

Comment: really thank you, your help.

but docker ps -a show nothing.



////////////
and docker exec -ti e9490eebd5fb1d161359d05192042be477d87aaa2e813e4fff69a329cd22675d bash
Error: No such container: e9490eebd5fb1d161359d05192042be477d87aaa2e813e4fff69a329cd22675d

Comment: If you launch with `docker run --rm` --> --rm means that container exits when entrypoint finishes. So, launch without `--rm` and you should see any container created  or exited. If it was created, access it with `docker exec -ti`. If it was exited, see `docker logs`

Comment: docker logs say
same error 190 ...

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help. I will study harder and help more people just like you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
docker run --rm -it tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.6 /bin/sh
```

Since you are using a Raspberry Pi, the CPU architecture is ARM. You are using `tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.5` but...

From [hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx/](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx/):

> ## What's new
>
> **Note**: although Raspberry Pi can now compile and run the image, Docker Hub doesn't have an automated building process for other architectures yet. https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1261 * 2017-12-09: The version based in Python 3.6 now supports multiple architectures apart from AMD64 using the new Docker multi-architecture features. It was tested on an ARMv7 32 bits (Raspberry Pi 3 B). To achieve that, the Python 3.6 version now uses a copy of the latest Nginx image which is based on the latest Debian version (Debian Stretch). In the official Python image, there's a Stretch version only for Python 3.6. So, that's the only one that can be merged with the current Nginx image. **That's why, in this image, only Python 3.6 supports multi-arch**.

Comment: even if, I can't run with same error
```
dokcer run tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.6
```

However, I did not think the image would have any compatibility issues. Thank you. I will also contact the image creator.